How to extract umask value from new instance bash shell with single command?
I can extract umask value from new instance bash shell with this method :
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ umask
0027
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ bash
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ umask
0002
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ 

But for me this is inefficient way, so I want to make it efficient by using single command to extract umask value from new instance shell.
I try to use single command bash -c "umask" to extract umask in new instance shell, but I think this is not working as I expected, it shows umask of the current shell:
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ umask
0027
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ bash
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ umask
0002
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ exit
exit
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$ bash -c "umask"
0027
[ansible@rhel8 ~]$

So the question is, how I can achieve umask from the new instance shell with single command ??

a single line: showumask=`umask`; echo $showumask - putting the command in \´ command` executes it before using.

If the new umask value is set in .bashrc, try adding the -i switch, like this: bash -ci "umask"

Thank you @Lacek, this is what I want to achieve.
